# react-native make whole screen black

Tags: react-native

In react-native(expo) I want to make whole screen black on push of a button. I mean I want to hide(show a fully black container on top of all areas of the screen including status bar. Does anyone know how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's quite simple.

Step 1 : Use a main parent view container to wrap all your content

Step 2 : Try giving it dynamic style or inline style based on state.

Step 3 : On Press of button update state and then as soon as the state changes make the view cover the whole screen.

Step 4 : Note- Use Dimensions.get('screen').height as it will cover whole screen including status bar.

```
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
    makeScreenBlack : false
        };
      }

      render() {
    const {makeScreenBlack} = this.state;

        return (
    <React.Fragment>
    makeScreenBlack === true && <View style={styles.mainView}/>
    {this.props.children} //Whatever you want to render.
    <Button onPress = {() =>this.setState({makeScreenBlack : true})}/>
    <React.Fragment>
        );
      }


    export default StyleSheet.create({
      mainView: {
    height : Dimensions.get('screen').height,
width : Dimensions.get('screen').width,
    backgroundColor : 'black'
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
    <Text style={{ color: "red" }}>Some Text</Text>
</View>
```